# feathers authenticate() How do I use it without the api call failing with no parameters?

Tags: aurelia, feathersjs

I put together a simple Aurelia app that attempts to authenticate, which works correctly, except when you refresh the browser and the constructor for the app checks to see if we are already authenticated, the API call fails.  I would expect the catch in the API call to return notification that the user is either not logged in already, or that the user is in fact already logged in based on a locally stored token.

From the docs: https://docs.feathersjs.com/authentication/client.html

> app.authenticate() attempts to authenticate with the server using the
>   data you passed it. **If you don't provide any options it will attempt
>   to authenticate using a token stored in memory or in your storage
>   engine.** It returns a promise.

Here is the complete test app I'm using to test this.  https://gitlab.com/sday/feathers-test

Here is the constructor code that appears to fail from: https://gitlab.com/sday/feathers-test/blob/master/src/app.js

```
constructor() {
    var parent=this;
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3030');
    this.f = feathers()
      .configure(feathers.socketio(socket))
      .configure(feathers.hooks())
      .configure(feathers.authentication({ storage: window.localStorage }));

    // This appears to be a problem.  If I am in fact already logged in, the callback is made, the token and user object is returned.
    // If the user is not logged in the catch isn't called, but an error is generated in the browser console.
    // Error: Could not find stored JWT and no authentication type was given
    // The docs indicate one should be able to call authenticate() without parameters to validate a current session.
    this.f.authenticate().then(function(result){
      console.log('Already Authenticated!', parent.f.get('token'));
      parent.email=parent.f.get('user').email;
      console.log("User:",parent.f.get('user'));
      parent.authenticated=true;
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.error('Not authenticated!', error);
      parent.authenticated=false;
    });
  }
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Well, a case of staring at the screen too long.  It is working as expected.  It is in the catch when the user is not logged in.  I was starring at the red thinking this was an exception rather than a console.error call inside the catch.  ugh

Comment: You can put the `authenticate()` function in the `activate()` function of the view, because the `activate` handles promises. `activate() { return this.f.authenticate(); }`

Comment: I still get the error.  If I'm logged in, it works.  If I do a feathers.logout() then refresh the browser I get the exception I put in question.

Comment: Use the application tab in chrome to look at the local storage to see if the JWT is there

Comment: It is not, but isn't that expected given I called feathers.logout()?  I would expect the api call to drop into the catch() rather than fail as an uncaught exception.  no?

Comment: have you breakpointed it?

Comment: Another thing you can do is move the configuration logic out into the `main.js` which bootstrap aurelia.

Comment: Oh Geeze, I've been staring at this too long.  It is in the catch!  It's working as expected.  Thanks for walking me through this one step at a time.  I can now see the light.  :) ugh

Comment: I was just trying to create a very succinct example to demonstrate my problem.  Even the promise in the constructor works fine, but points well taken. I have the logic in a separate session.js class that I inject into views/models that need session info.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is actually being printed by your catch logic:

```
}).catch(function(error){
  console.error('Not authenticated!', error);
  parent.authenticated=false;
});
```

Your exception in the chrome debugger starts with `Not Authenticated!`.